# Stochastic gradient descent (SGD)

Tags: objective-function

The objective function  ()   =   [1∑=1Lossℎ(()⋅())]+2‖‖2

where  Lossℎ()=max{0,1−}  is the hinge loss function,  ((),())  with for  =1,…  are the training examples, with  ()∈{1,−1}  being the label for the vector  ().

how to find the sgd with respect to theta for when  ⋅≤1 is it y*x and is it 0 when ⋅>1